# How to put TypeScript sources into separate VS project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript

I have a long-running web project (3-4 years old), which is based on ASP.NET MVC 5. I have a large client-side codebase too, written in TypeScript. Due to earlier conventions, the TypeScript sources are part of the MVC 5 `csproj` project, so it gets compiled together with the back-end.

This structure is very unfortunate due to many reasons. A few main ones are: violation of SRP, strongly coupled to backend, no way to separately maintain and build backend, no way to separately maintain and build front-end, etc.

I'd like to separate the client-side codebase into a new Visual Studio project, however, I have no idea what the best way would be, as Visual Studio doesn't provide a way to have clean TypeScript projects (at least as far as I know).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript 2.0. What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your client-side code (the TypeScript application) does not need its own `Web.config` file — that is, you don't need to configure IIS authorization, redirects, etc. — you can simply **use the *"HTML Application with TypeScript"* project type in Visual Studio**.

However, if both your client and server code need their own `Web.config` and they get deployed to the same IIS web site, having two separate ASP.NET projects becomes more difficult, because one needs to merge two `Web.config` files… which is impossible, AFAIK.

I was facing a similar problem, but in my case I had a AngularJS-based web application programmed in TypeScript, and an ASP.NET Web API backend.

The best I could think of so far that doesn't require any additional build steps was to not move the TypeScript code into a separate project, but to **move the Web API / MVC code instead**. The client-side TypeScript ends up in the ASP.NET web project, the Web API goes into a class library.

Two remaining pain points are the shared `Web.config` and bootstrapping Web API via `Global.asax`, which ends up in the "wrong" project. Regarding the `Web.config`, it might be possible to further extract Web API configuration into a separate `.config` file via the `configSource` mechanism. I don't see a way to get the Web API bootstrapping in `Global.asax` out of the (otherwise client-only code) ASP.NET project.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I was thinking about it but it sounds a bit dirty to me. I've just found the project type `HTML application with TypeScript`, I'm experimenting with it now.

Comment: Sounds good. If you find a way to merge that TypeScript project's `Web.config` with your ASP.NET MVC 5's `Web.config`, I'd appreciate if you posted your solution as an answer here!

Comment: The `HTML Application with TypeScript` project type seems to work. At first glance it seems like a little empty Web project with preconfigured TypeScript support. I've just copied all the sources and typings and it seems to be working fine. I guess it wasn't present that time when you had to make the decision.

Comment: I don't see right now why I'd need to merge the TypeScript project's `web.config` into the Web MVC project's one. While it is present in the TypeScript project indeed, it has almost no content, seems like just a *technical thing*. I think I'll even try to delete it as it has only a couple of seemingly irrelevant settings.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: For me, that project type was available, but I wasn't (and still am not) aware of any way to merge the two `Web.config` files. In the client-side project, I might need a `Web.config` e.g. to restrict certain URL paths to certain user groups (think "admin console") using `<location>`, in the Web API project I need it to configure Web API, authentication, connection strings, etc. That's why I couldn't completely separate the client and server projects. But if you don't need a `Web.config` for your client-side code, then the TypeScript project appears to be the right way to go.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I plan to stay with publishing only the single MVC project. I'll copy all the outputs of the *client project* (like the compiled `js`, and `css` files, etc.) to the main MVC project using for example a simple post-build script, so this project will be really only a dev environment layer.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: Sounds reasonable. Be aware that as soon as you have build event scripts (such as `xcopy`-ing files between two project output directories), incremental builds might no longer work; Visual Studio will do full rebuilds every single time. (At least that was the case back in Visual Studio 2010.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't experience that so far fortunately. If you add the option to use the `HTML Application with TypeScript` project type to your answer for the sake of summarizing the comments, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: Done. Good luck with your project, and a happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

IMO, client side code like your javascript or css should be together with your "backend" code, the backend code doesn't mean to be your entire backend code, it should be a thin controller layer application which only handle http request and server side rendering

you could separate your monolithic application into multiple `service layer` and one `frontend layer` which only handle httprequest and rendering

the problem to separate only javascript and css into a single project is

1. it makes deployment complex, when you have incompatibility between your client code and server code, you don't know which should be deploy first
2. you can't do js hash (you don't need to deal with client cache) when you separate your client code from backend

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already have a thin controller layer with underlying business service layers, but still I need this separation for other reasons.